# Wp-cron with add_action

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have these features to schedule tasks in wordpress, the code runs smoothly but the function "post", nothing prints ..

what I want to do is:
that from input data, a task is scheduled on wordpress and parameters are sent to the function that prints the values entered

```
 function info($nombre){

     if(!wp_next_scheduled($nombre)) {
         wp_schedule_event(time(),'hourly',$nombre,array('Hola', 'Mundo'));

            //Deployment hook

           add_action($nombre, 'post','10',2 );
               }    
        else {
            echo 'no se creo el cron para la campaña: '. $snombre;

        }



    }  

    //funcion hook
    function post($param1,$param2){
        echo "<p>Action for cron..... hook...</p>".$param1;
        echo $param2;
        }
```

Comment: what I want to do is:
that from input data, a task is scheduled on wordpress and parameters are sent to the function that prints the values entered

Answer (score 0):

I have edited some of possible misspellings, would it work for you now?

```
function info($nombre){

    if(!wp_next_scheduled($nombre)) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', $nombre, array( 'Hola', 'Mundo'));
        //Deployment hook
        add_action($nombre, 'post','10',2 );
    }    
    else {
       echo 'no se creo el cron para la campaña: '. $nombre;
    }
}  

//funcion hook
function post($param1,$param2){
   echo "<p>Action for cron..... hook...</p>" . $param1;
   echo $param2;
}
```

Comment: what I want to do is:
that from input data, a task is scheduled on wordpress and parameters are sent to the function that prints the values entered